# Android session handling

Tags: java, android, session, authentication

How do I manage a session in an Android app after the user successfully logs in? Should I use `SharedPreferences` or static variables to store the session info?
The user must log in every time the app launches too.

Comment: What kind of login? CookieStore perhaps?

Comment: You should use shared preference because static variable's value doesn't exist when your app will be killed.

Comment: if you want to login again when app opens then there is no need for session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Account Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). It was designed for it. Here is a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html) for it.

Anyway it is not recomended to use preferences for it, because at the end it is plain XML file, so anyone can steal data from it. Also it is not recomended to use static variables, because you never know when your process will be killed. For example somebody could call to your phone and android could kill your app and restart it after call ends.

Comment: Ok, but where does the Account Manger store the credentials?

Comment: In internal database

Comment: Is this database can be accessible in rooted devices ?

Comment: Yes, please check paragraph "Be Smart About Security!" here - https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html